# Is it possible to get the latest seq number of PouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to cover for an issue where CouchDB is rolled back, causing PouchDB to be in the future.  I want to find a way to detect this situation and force PouchDB to destroy and reload when this happens.

Is there a way to ask PouchDB for it's current pull seq number?  I am not able to find any documentation at all on this.  My google-foo is not strong enough.

So far my only thought is to watch the sync.on(change) feed, and record the seq number on every pull.  Then on app reload, run this as ajax `https:/server/db/_changes?descending=true&limit=1` and verify that the seq number this returns, is higher than the seq number I stored. If the stored seq is higher, then pouchdb.destroy(), purge `_pouch_` from indexdb, and probably figure out how to delete websql versions for this release https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/tag/6.4.2.

Or is there a better way to solve situations where PouchDB ends up in the future ahead of CouchDB?

Comment: Please, could you explain a bit more the idea of rollback in CouchBD? Which is the exact case? PouchDB will put in sync the last seq after each replication even if you have a higher sequence in PouchDB

Comment: Catastrophic hardware failure and CouchDb restored from backup.  Or in our test environment, Catastrophic test data that is rolled back to a copy of live for testing again.  What I am finding is PouchDb stops syncing until CouchDb seq catches up to what PouchDb expects.  And of course, CouchDb refreshed to clear tombstones.

Comment: To be more clear, say my profile is at revision 170, then CoucDb is rolled back and my profile is at version 120.  PouchDb doesn't see this change, it loads it's own copy of 170, doesn't push it, and get's really confused when the next change is version 121.

Comment: @JuanjoRodriguez If PouchDb doesn't care about the seq number.  Could I in theory fix this roll back problem by simply having a script to run through all relevant documents, pick them up and put them back down with a new revision, thus making a change and triggering pouchDb to get the latest changes?

Comment: In this case you probably will run into document conflicts. Is your replication pull, push or both?

Comment: @JuanjoRodriguez Live sync with specific documents using filter `"by_doc_list": "function (doc, req) {return doc._id === '_design/db' || req.query.docs.indexOf(doc._id) !== -1;}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the replication checkpoint documents. When you recover a database from the backup, probably, you are recovering also the checkpoint local documents.

You should remove all local docs, by finding them with the _local_docs endpoint and then removing form the recovered database.

Doing this, your PouchDB should try to send to CouchDB their docs syncing back PouchDB and CouchDB.

Comment: Interesting, so run this `https://server/db/_local_docs`, loop through "rows" to get `id "_local/iy183t4BF_SQwHOezT1KmA=="` and send a delete with that ID?  Although I don't necessarily want PouchDb to push back the changes, just roll itself back too.

Comment: Yes, when PouchDB try to find the Checkpoint and it is not present, the replication starts from the beginning

Comment: Would that cause pouchDb to roll back as well? As in my example, re-retrieving the older profile?  I am confused as to why it doesn't do this accidentally if the checkpoints are stored in the database, then they should have also been rolled back, or in effect, deleted.  And since pouchDb's checkpoint that it stopped at no longer exists, shouldn't it roll back?  Or does pouchDb need every checkpoint gone before it acts?  Also, does it need something to trigger it to act? That document has 325,923 rows! Wow

Comment: Would that cause PouchDb to roll back as well? No, Probably, the document in PouchDB will be send to CouchDB.

Comment: Hmm, then yeah, I need PouchDb to roll back as well in this situation. Or at least be able to detect the problem and destroy->recreate itself.

Comment: I have a new evolution of this problem, meaning my idea of a solution is no longer valid. I hope you can help, I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045600/pouchdb-replicate-of-single-document-causes-huge-memory-usage-then-crash